# Flexbox with horizontal scrolling and fixed width elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I want both `.right` and `.button` to be of fixed width, the `.left` should take up the remaining space (i.e. responsive) and the `.overflowing-text` to overflow with a horizontal scrollbar.

I have checked other similar questions and answers, but I'm just not able to make this work.

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: silver;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.right {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2em;
    width: 6em;
    flex: 1;
}
.text-container {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.overflowing-text {
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.button {
    flex: 1;
    width: 6em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="text-container">
            <div class="overflowing-text">This text needs a horizontal scroll bar when it overflows</div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">6em fixed W</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex can have a initial width `flex: 0 0 6em`. Might work for you

Answer (score 2):

you have to add `white-space:nowrap; overflow-x :scroll;` in the `.overflowing-text`

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: silver;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left {
    background-color: grey;
     width:8em;
}
.right {
    background-color: #fff;
    flex: 0 0 6em;
}
.text-container {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.overflowing-text {
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x :scroll;
}
.button {
    flex: 1;
    width: 6em;
    border: 1px solid red;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="text-container">
            <div class="overflowing-text">This text needs a horizontal scroll bar when it overflows</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
    <div class="right">6em fixed W</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you added `width:8em;` to `.left` ... which does not make it responsive. I've edited the question to clarify that part.